# Getting error with React native navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native-navigation

I am trying to create a react native app using typescript, i am not able to get the react-native-navigation dependency working.

I get the following error

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ react-native run-android
warn Package react-native-navigation contains invalid configuration: "dependency.assets" is not allowed,"dependency.hooks" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.
info JS server already running.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\keint\Documents\GitHub\expense_manager_app\node_modules\react-native-navigation\lib\android\app\build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-navigation'.
> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-navigation'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
error Failed to install the app.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

this is the App.tsx file

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();


function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Dashboard"
            component={DashboardScreen}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}
```

I tried to re-install the node modules as well as re-build the gradle but none of that worked